# Migrating MySQL user and DB to another host

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database with some users and several DBs each one starting with `username_` (guess who can access them...).

Since I'm migrating some websites from a host to another, mantaining the same directory structure and DB hostname as configured in webapps, I want to migrate both all the DBs belonging to a single user **and** the `GRANT` associated to that user, since I don't know the password of him.

I've found [how to move the data](http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-backup-and-restore-export-and-import-mysql-databases-tutorial/) (just add an scp command and voilà), but do you know how to migrate a user and keep its password too?

By the way, I'm manually moving only one user at a time, so no need to automate for everyone. Short downtime is acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user database in the special database named: **mysql**, if you migrate it then the users will be migrated.